# PasswordResetTokenGenerator.make_token() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'

Tags: python, django, django-views

```
   message2 = render_to_string('email_confirmation.html',{
            'name': myuser.first_name,
            'domain': current_site.domain,
            'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(myuser.pk)),
            'token': generate_token.make_token(myuser)
        })
```

this is my code and I get the above error message

Comment: What is `generate_token`?

Comment: @Benjamin Welcome to StackOverflow! Please follow [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to create a minimal reproducible example for us to help you better. Please post the *full* error message as well. Also, as Guy pointed out, you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73183450/edit) your question instead of adding an answer to add more information.

Comment: Assuming `generate_token` is a class then you need to instanciate it first if `make_token` is not static method. try `generate_token().make_token(myuser)`